# Adjointable operators of a certain Hilbert module

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

In Lances book on Hilbert modules he states that if I have a C*-algebra $A$ and a (right) Hilbert module $E$ over $A$ then I can make the $n^{th}$ direct sum of $E$, denoted $E^n$, into a (right) Hilbert $M_n(A)$ module by seeing $x\in E^n$ as a row vector $x=(x_1,...x_n)$ and doing matrix multiplication. I.e. if $a\in M_n(A)$ then $xa=\sum x_ia_{ij}$ moreover we can equip it with the right $M_n(A)$ inner product given by $\langle x,y\rangle=(\langle x_i,y_j\rangle)_{ij}$. I see why this is a right Hilbert module and the construction looks like the exterior tensor product of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $E$ where I use the $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ valued inner product. Now Lance claims that the adjointables $\mathcal{L}(E^n)\cong M_n(\mathcal{L}(E))$ and I'm not sure how to see this holding, can anyone help me with this? In general we have that with the exterior product of two Hilbert modules one has in this case the following containment $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)\otimes \mathcal{L}(E) \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n\otimes E)$ but the left hand side is just isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}(E)$ how do I in general find $\mathcal{L}(E^n)$?

Comment: Have you tried "definition shoving"? This looks like something where one of the inclusions is easy (every element of $M_n(\mathcal L(E))$ induces an element of $\mathcal L(E^n)$ in a natural manner) and for the other you take the definition and you just mash it a couple of times until you get the other side. After that you think of some clever reason why that direction is very natural and right - thus gaining greater insight into the subject.

Comment: My problem is I dont see how something in $M_n(\mathcal{L}(E))$ naturally induces an element of $\mathcal{L}(E^n)$. one can write for $x\in E^n$ $T(x)=(\sum T_{ik}x_k)$. But it is not clear that this morphism will be adjointable when each $T_{ik}$ is. The inner products yield $\langle Tx,y\rangle=(\sum_k \langle T_{ik}(x_k),y_j \rangle)_{ij}$ and if there was an adjoint it'd have to be given by $S$ such that $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,Sy\rangle=(\langle x_i\sum_{l} S_{jl}(y_l)\rangle)_{i,j}$ now it's not clear to me you can build such an $S$ from the adjoints of each $T_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T\in M_n(\mathcal L(E))$ with coefficients $T_{ij}$, then for $\vec x, \vec y\in E^n$ you have

$$\langle \vec y, T\vec x\rangle = \sum_{ij} \langle y_i, T_{ij} x_j\rangle = \sum_{ij}\langle (T_{ij})^* y_i, x_j\rangle = \langle T^* \vec y, \vec x\rangle$$
where $(T^*)_{ij}=(T_{ji})^*$, ie the matrix is transposed and you take the adjoint of its coefficients. Hence the $A$-linear map given by the matrix $T$ is adjointable if the matrix components are adjointable.

For the other direction if $T:E^n\to E^n$ is $A$-linear and admits an adjoint $T^*$ denote with $T_{ij}$ the map $E\to E$ given by including $E$ into the $j$-the component of $E^n$, applying $T$ and then projecting onto the $i$-the component, ie
$$T_{ij}:E\overset{\mathrm{incl}_j}\to E^n \overset T\to E^n\overset{\mathrm{proj}_i}\to E,$$
this defines the components of the matrix associated to $T$. Why are the components adjointable? Well:
$$\langle y, T_{ij} x\rangle = \langle \mathrm{incl}_i[y], T (\mathrm{incl}_j[x])\rangle = \langle T^*(\mathrm{incl}_i[y]), \mathrm{incl}_j[x]\rangle = \langle (T^*)_{ji}y,x\rangle$$
and $(T_{ij})^*= (T^*)_{ji}$ as we should expect from the first part.

Comment: I think you have misread my question, I am seeing $E^n$ as an $M_n(A)$ module not an $A$ module the inner product not being the one you've checked but instead the one taking $\langle x,y\rangle=(\langle x_i,y_j\rangle)_{ij}$ the matrix with entries those inner products. These are different Hilbert modules.

Comment: I have misread your question you are right. However if you take $A=\Bbb C$, $n=2$ and $H=\Bbb C$ asking that an element $a$ of $M_2$ is adjointable is the same as asking that there be a $b\in M_2$ for which:
$$\langle \vec y, a\vec x\rangle = \overline{\vec y} \cdot (a\cdot \vec x)^T = (\overline{\vec y}\cdot x^T)\cdot a^T \overset!= b\cdot (\overline{\vec y}\cdot \vec x) = ... = \langle b \vec y, \vec x\rangle$$
holds for every $\vec y, \vec x$ in $\Bbb C^2$. This will not work for all $a\in M_2(\Bbb C)$! For example $a=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ does not admit any such $b$.

Comment: ... for with this $a$ and $\vec y = (0,1)= \vec x$ you get $\langle \vec y, a\vec x\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ while $\langle b\vec y ,\vec  x\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0& b_{12}\\ 0& b_{22}\end{pmatrix}$. So not every element of $M_2(\mathcal L(\Bbb C))$ is adjointable with this inner product on $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: right but I think there may be another way of seeing $M_n(\mathcal{L}(E^n))\cong \mathcal{L}_{M_n(A)}(E^n)$ as Lance claims this a couple of times in his book (Hilbert modules a toolkit for operator algebras).For example see page 39 and 58, but I'm not sure how to see it.

Comment: On page 58 the isomorphism $\mathcal L_{M_n(A)}(E^n) \cong \mathcal L_A(E^n)$ is given as $\pi_\tau$, the localisation of the trace map $\tau$. The above answer describes the relatively simple isomorphism $\mathcal L_{A}(E^n) \cong M_n(\mathcal L_A(E))$, so whats left is to understand what $\pi_\tau$ is and why it is an isomorphism. I'll read the relevant part and update the answer if I get there in time.

Comment: Yeah i'm quite confused with this localization map, I don't see why it's clear that it is subjective in general!

Comment: I think surjectivity is false in general and believe I have a counter-example (its essentially the example in the comments above). Anyway I asked a question focussed only on the localisation and the statement on whether or not it is surjective for faithful retractions or not: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714053/does-localisation-of-a-faithful-retraction-induce-an-isomorphism-between-adjoint

Comment: @sirjoe the other question now has an answer, it seems very likely now that the statement in the book is wrong.